# Accessing Field Settings of Pivot Table using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, pivot-table

I am creating a workbook with a sheet populated data from a data source then creating a second sheet with a pivot table view of that data. Everything works fine, but I can't seem to change the default look of the pivot table. I am trying to get the setting ( Row Labels-->Click one from the list-->Field Settings-->Subtotals-->None  and Row Labels-->Click one from the list-->Field Settings-->Layout & Print-->'Show item labels in tabular form' ) checked while creating the pivot table but couldn't find the handle / flag in the POI. Tried finding something under pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition() or pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotTableStyleInfo(), but no lock. Please advise if there is a way to set these settings using poi during pivot table creation, not after the fact following the steps mentioned in the parenthesis. Here is my pivot table code :

```
XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet)wb.createSheet("Data");
...
...
//filling data sheet, skipping this part as it's not relevant 
...
XSSFSheet pivotSheet = (XSSFSheet)wb.createSheet("Pivot Table");
AreaReference source = new AreaReference(sheet.getSheetName()+"!A$1:W$"+String.valueOf(sheet.getLastRowNum()));
CellReference position = new CellReference("A3");
XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = pivotSheet.createPivotTable(source, position);


        /* Add filters */
        pivotTable.addRowLabel(17);
        pivotTable.addRowLabel(20);
        pivotTable.addRowLabel(21);
        pivotTable.addRowLabel(22);
        pivotTable.addRowLabel(13);
        pivotTable.addRowLabel(19);
        pivotTable.addRowLabel(6);
        pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);
        pivotTable.addRowLabel(18);
        pivotTable.addRowLabel(1);
        pivotTable.addRowLabel(7);
        pivotTable.addRowLabel(9);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured it out; lack of good documentation forced me to try a zillion things and finally was able to achieve what I wanted; here is the code :

```
for(CTPivotField ctPivotField:pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldList()){
            ctPivotField.setAutoShow(false);
            ctPivotField.setOutline(false);
            ctPivotField.setSubtotalTop(false);
            ctPivotField.setSubtotalCaption("");
        }
```

Comment: There is one issue here though, ctPivotField.setSubtotalCaption(""); doesn't actually remove the cell, ctPivotField.setSubtotalCaption(null); also doesn't remove the subtotal cell, so still searching for a way to mark pivot field's subtotal stting to 'none'

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm looking to do the same thing.

Comment: @ToddSharp instead of creating the pivot table every time, I created one template XLS file with all the desired styling and included that in the source, now I am opening that file filling the necessary data in the source tab, and saving the XLS file with the dynamic data with a different name;  since the Pivot table tab is marked to refresh when opened, it does the work. Instead of going through the POI API with the limitations on Pivot Tables, creating a template and using it is much easier and flexible if you will generate the same styled pivot table for dynamic data.

Comment: @UCJava how did you do it with creating a pivot table template and then filling it with data n java? please could give me an example or hint how to edi data oft existing pivot table in java?

Comment: @ninjaxelite see my below example

Answer (score 2):

instead of creating the pivot table every time, I created one template XLS file with all the desired styling and included that in the source, now I am opening that file filling the necessary data in the source tab, and saving the XLS file with the dynamic data with a different name; since the Pivot table tab is marked to refresh when opened, it does the work. Instead of going through the POI API with the limitations on Pivot Tables, creating a template and using it is much easier and flexible if you will generate the same styled pivot table for dynamic data.

Comment: this was a while but example is much appreciated

Comment: I am doing the same. But in my case, when there is more than ten records in the source sheet, the calculations in the pivot table are correct but there are some rows that overflows from the Pivot table.
Here is the link to my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48443001/updating-pivot-datasource-using-apache-poi

Please advise

Answer (score 1):

@ninjaxelite here how it goes :

```
       List<Object[]> resultSet = //get raw data


        XSSFWorkbook wb = null;
        try {
            wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(this.getClass().getResource("/content/XLS_template.xlsx").getPath()));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            //error
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            //error
        }



        Map<String, CellStyle> styles = createStyles(wb); // some local function to get styles 
        XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet)wb.getSheetAt(0);

        XSSFRow row;
        XSSFCell cell;
        int rowNum = 0;
        for (Object[] aRow : resultSet) {
            rowNum++;
            row = sheet.createRow(rowNum);

            cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue((String)aRow[0]);
            cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("cell_normal_centered"));

             ...
             ..
             .
```

Comment: The problem is you have to extend the area of data source for the pivot table if you have more data rows than in the template. otherwise it will not take all the available rows for the pivot table but only the rows from the template area reference.

Comment: I simply extended the data source area in the template to the maximum. Now its working purrfectly, thank you.

Comment: the above code will also do the same dynamically; when you add row by calling the : "row = sheet.createRow(rowNum);", you are basically extending the data source. The code does't care how much of data you place in.