# Updating Pivot Datasource using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am working on a task in which there is an excel template which have a pivot table and an excel sheet as a datasource for that pivot table. I am updating the datasource sheet using Apache POI library in Java. If there are 1 or 2 records in the Datasource sheet, the pivot table is fine. But if there is more than 5 or 6, then it overflows from Pivot table. Attached is the screen shot for the issue I am facing. [image]

What can possibly the issue? And how can I get away with this?
Thanks!

Comment: I am using Apache POI 3.9

Comment: "What can possibly the issue?": Your code which you are not showing, especially the code part which updates the pivot cache. Or the usage of such an ancient version of  `apache poi` such as version 3.9.